# On Android 6.0 drawOval draws a rectangle when paint style is set to Pain.Style.STROKE

Tags: android, canvas, android-6.0-marshmallow, drawrectangle

Starting with Android 6 the drawOval method seems to draw a rectangle instead of a circle when paint style is set to Paint.Style.STROKE.
If paint style is set to the Paint.Style.FILL or FILL_AND_STROKE everything seems to be fine.
See how it looks in next pictures.

[image: Pre Android 6]

**Pre Android 6**

[image: Android 6]

**Android 6**

The green rectangle is supposed to be the green circle from the scale

Note that the drawing is made in a rectangle with 1.0f by 1.0f dimensions.
Everything works fine on all Android versions excepting 6.0.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I manage it by using helper function that re-scale the canvas to a bigger rectangle (100x100), draws the circle and the scale back the canvas to original size.

```
public static void drawOval(Canvas canvas, RectF rectangle, Paint paint, float scale) {
    float originalStrokeWidth = paint.getStrokeWidth();
    float upScaling = 100f;
    paint.setStrokeWidth(originalStrokeWidth * upScaling);
    canvas.save();
    RectF newRect = new RectF();
    newRect.left = rectangle.left*upScaling;
    newRect.top = rectangle.top*upScaling;
    newRect.right = rectangle.right*upScaling;
    newRect.bottom = rectangle.bottom*upScaling;
    canvas.scale(scale/upScaling, scale/upScaling);
    canvas.drawOval(newRect, paint);
    canvas.restore();
    paint.setStrokeWidth(originalStrokeWidth);
}
public static void drawOval(Canvas canvas, RectF rectangle, Paint paint) {
    drawOval(canvas, rectangle, paint, 1f);
}
```

So, where I had canvas.drawOval(rect, paint) I replace it with 
CanvasUtils.drawOval(canvas, rect, paint);

I have notice that "bug" happens only when I use a bitmap as canvas and draw that bitmap as background of the gauge.